# Insert data from one MySQL to another MySQL instance

Tags: mysql

I have 2 servers running mysql and they have the same database/table, but with different entries. There was a reason for that, but now I need to merge these databases. I've made a dump of the whole database in server 1 and I want to insert these data into the database of server 2. The problem is: How do I insert this data just incrementing the database of server 2? I can't lose the data that already is on server 2.

Comment: You may restore your dump into separate database (with some temporary name) then merge data. Special procedure must be created for this operation.

Comment: And have you thought about foreign key clashes?

Comment: It's a very simple database, there is one table with a few columns, no foreign keys. I just need to insert the data from the dump file to the database without the IDs to avoid conflict with the data that's already there.